# Eshell sudo does not accept option

Tags: emacs, sudo, eshell

In the eshell prompt the -E option can't be passe.
I end with the following error:

```
$ sudo -E gmake install
-E: command not found
```

Does someone have a solution to that?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the Eshell built-in sudo.  Do a

```
% which sudo
```

to see and look here: http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/Built_002dins.html.

You can do

```
% *sudo -E gmake install
```

to call the usual command.